# MySQL - Number and text in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I was surprised when I run two statement in MySQL

```
SELECT *
FROM jobs
WHERE salary_max = 1000
```

AND

```
SELECT *
FROM jobs
WHERE salary_max = '1000'
```

I've just wonder that why MySQL can process text and number as the same, and it return same result. Can you explain for me about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL automatically converts incompatible types in expressions to make them compatible. It's discussed in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html).

Answer (score 2):

When an operator is used with operands of different types, type conversion occurs to make the operands compatible. Some conversions occur implicitly. For example, MySQL automatically converts numbers to strings as necessary, and vice versa.

```
mysql> SELECT 1+'1';
    -> 2
mysql> SELECT CONCAT(2,' test');
    -> '2 test'
```

for further rules and descriptions please refer to mysql documentation

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html